# Android MediaRecorder start failed: -12

Tags: android, mediarecorder

I've been trying to make an app (API 8) that records video, without audio. I've followed the instructions on the Android tutorial. My code is as follows:

```
    mCamera.unlock();
    recorder = new MediaRecorder();
    recorder.setCamera(mCamera);
    recorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.DEFAULT);
    recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.DEFAULT);
    recorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.DEFAULT);
    recorder.setOutputFile(getOutputMediaFile(MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO).toString());
           //getOutputMediaFile returns a file path where the video will be saved
    recorder.setPreviewDisplay(mHolder.getSurface());
    try {
        recorder.prepare();
        recorder.start();
        recording = true;
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        System.out.println("Error preparing recorder");
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Error preparing video output");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

When it reaches `recorder.start()`, the program crashes, throwing an `IllegalStateException` that can't be caught, along with an error code `start failed: -12`.
The only other info I could find about this error code was in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11766779/mediarecorder-start-failed-12) post, but it doesn't give a very clear answer, nor is the model I'm using any of the ones addressed in the post.

Can anyone help identify what the error is and suggest a solution?

Comment: possible duplicate of [MediaRecorder "start failed -12"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11766779/mediarecorder-start-failed-12)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So now I´ve tried an example and downloaded the sources. I modified it with Your code and it works without saving sound on API 8. Here is the main class:

```
    public class AndroidVideoCapture extends Activity implements SurfaceHolder.Callback{

Button myButton;
MediaRecorder mediaRecorder;
SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder;
boolean recording;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    recording = false;

    mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
    initMediaRecorder();

    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    SurfaceView myVideoView = (SurfaceView)findViewById(R.id.videoview);
    surfaceHolder = myVideoView.getHolder();
    surfaceHolder.addCallback(this);
    surfaceHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);

    myButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.mybutton);
    myButton.setOnClickListener(myButtonOnClickListener);
}

private Button.OnClickListener myButtonOnClickListener 
= new Button.OnClickListener(){

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(recording){
            mediaRecorder.stop();
            mediaRecorder.release();
            finish();
        }else{
            mediaRecorder.start();
            recording = true;
            myButton.setText("STOP");
        }
    }};

@Override
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    prepareMediaRecorder();
}
@Override
public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

private void initMediaRecorder(){

    mediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.DEFAULT);
    mediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.DEFAULT);
    mediaRecorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.DEFAULT);
    mediaRecorder.setOutputFile("/sdcard/myvideo.mp4");
}

private void prepareMediaRecorder(){
    mediaRecorder.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder.getSurface());
    try {
        mediaRecorder.prepare();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

The difference to Your code is, that in this tutorial no camera is instantiated. It only works with MediaRecorder. The other difference is, that the prepare() and start() methods are separated. The MediaRecorder is initialized at starting the app, prepared when SurfaceView is created,  and started at button click. Maybe You should try to seperate them too and don´t use camera. Please try it that way and give me a feedback if it works.

Comment: Apparently, if I don't use `setProfile()`, unlocking the camera and calling `MediaRecorder.setCamera()` will cause it to crash. Using `setProfile()` seems to resolve this issue. I decided to peek into the android source, and found out that `setProfile()` not only calls `setOutputFormat()` and `setVideoEncoder()`, but also `setVideoSize()`, `setEncodingBitRate()`, and `setVideoFrameRate()`. Adding these method calls fixes the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Have You tried to set MediaRecorder Profile?

```
    recorder.setProfile(CamcorderProfile.get(camId, CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_LOW));
```

There is a similar question here in sof at:

[MediaRecorder "start failed -12"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11766779/mediarecorder-start-failed-12)

Comment: According to the Android tutorials, `setOutputFormat()`, `setVideoEncoder()`, and `setAudioEncoder()` is an alternative to using `setProfile()`, which did not become available until API 8. I don't want the video to have any sound, which is why I'm not using `setProfile()`--unless `setAudioSource()` is called beforehand, it throws an exception, which pretty much forces the video to use sound. Calling `setOutputFormat()` and `setVideoEncoder()`, according to the documentation and tutorial, should be able to record video without sound.

Comment: ok.Did you call the steps recommended in the developer guide mCamera.open(), mCamera.setPreviewDisplay() and mCamera.startPreview() before unlocking the camera? I mean this dev guide: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html#capture-video

Comment: yes, but I can´t see the steps for your camera (not for recorder) open(),setPreviewDisplay() and startPreview(). That´s why I´m asking for.

Comment: I call those when the activity starts. They work fine, I can see the preview and take still photos.

Comment: ok, so give me little bit time. At weekend I try to do my own record app and maybe I can find a solution or at least why there is an exception.

Comment: Hi there, look at my new answer, I tried an example and it works without saving sound.